# Nginx rewrite without trailing slash

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have a rewrite rule for nginx:
`rewrite /(.*)(.html) /$1 permanent;` but it only works with a trailing slash, how can I make it work without a trailing slash?

Comment: Post complete config and a `curl -v http://yoururl.html` one with trailing slash url and one without. Update the question with your logs

Comment: one returns 404, one returns 200...not sure I got your reply

Comment: Post nginx logs and post complete nginx config

Comment: Config:
`rewrite /(.*)(.html) /$1 permanent;`

`access.log` is loaded with data, one entry returns 200 and one 400...

Comment: I need to see config from start to end. There might be some issue thats not picked up from just this line

Comment: How can I add a rule for this:
domain.com/my-page-one-1.html

to redirect to
domain.com/my-page-one-1/

?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153609/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-broshi).

Answer (score 0):

Your rewrite rule should be

```
rewrite ^(.*)\.html$ $1/ permanent;
```

And you should use `permanent`, only once your config works fine.